# Accessing Environment variables in Serverless C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, environment-variables, serverless-framework

I am working on Serverless project that runs with C#. I create the Boilerplate code from [this](https://github.com/pharindoko/serverlessDotNetStarter/) repo.
So my question is how I access the environment variables that are mentioned in the `serverless.yml` file for use inside the methods. My `serverless.yml` file looks like this.

```
service: doc-header

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore3.1
  environment: 
    MONGODB_URL: ${ssm:/mongoUrl/${self:provider.stage}~true}

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  docHeaderUpdator:
    handler: AwsDotnetCsharp::AwsDotnetCsharp.Handler::TestFunction
    package:
      artifact: bin/release/netcoreapp3.1/hello.zip
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: 
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - TestUserQueue
              - Arn
          batchSize: 10
          maximumBatchingWindow: 10

resources:
  Resources:
    TestUserQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "TestUserQueue-${opt:stage,self:provider.stage}"
        FifoQueue: true
        VisibilityTimeout: 200
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 102800
        ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 5
```

I have tried using,

```
var mongoUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_URL");
```

But seems that not working.

Comment: That is how you would access the value. Have you confirmed the value is actually set to what you would expect in the Lambda's environment variables by inspecting it in the AWS Console? I would have expected the value to be something like `ssm://...` (two slashes) to be a URI, rather than one slash, so maybe you're not _setting_ the value properly, which is why it "doesn't work".

Comment: I understood the issue I think. I have tested this with the Lambda test tool and it cannot fetch the value like this.

Comment: Serverless won't set up the Lambda test tool for you. You need to set the environment variables for the Lambda test tool to use either on your local computer or manually in the debug profile you use with it (I assume you're using it via Visual Studio?)

Comment: I am using VSCode.

Comment: The same applies - serverless is configuring AWS, not your local computer. You will need to manually configure environment variables for the Lambda Test Tool.

Comment: Yes, I understood, I have added this part to `launch.json` and it worked. ```"env": {
        "MongoDBUrl": "url"
      }``` Thank you @MartinCostello for clearing out my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As [Martin Costello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064169/martin-costello) explained in comments, Lambda Test Tool 3.1 cannot identify Environment variables set by the serverless.yml, even it cannot recognize the local environment variables set in your local device. If you deploy it to AWS and then `serverless.yml` can apply Environment Variables to the Lambda Runtime as same as normal NodeJS runtime.

If you need to test with Environment variables to the local environment as well without writing any other code by utilizing the same,

```
var mongoUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_URL");
```

implementation.
So in my case, I am using VSCode as debugging environment, So I can set Environment variables by adding this part to your `launch.json` file.

```
"env": {         
   "MongoDBUrl": "url"       
},
```

Full `launch.json` will look like this.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "/Users/sandunn/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1",
      // More information:
      // https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool#configure-for-visual-studio-code,
      // https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool#configure-for-visual-studio-for-mac
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      // Add your Environment variables here.
      "env": {
        "MongoDBUrl": "url" 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```